Redirect local WhatsApp directory to second partition ext4 in microSD in Android 10
I have googled from a month ago about on how to reach my goal, and I have found only How to bind mount a folder inside /sdcard with correct permissions?
My goal is to link the WhatsApp directory in Samsung Galaxy S9 running Android 10 (so it is storage/emulated/0) in the second partition of my microSD card in ext4 (I have chosen that filesystem because I have got some issues when coping some data inside exFAT partition, related discussion if you are interested in XDA Forums)
Now, in the upper link, there are 2 modes but both doesn't satisfy me:

MOUNT SD CARD MANUALLY: but it's referred only to exFAT or FAT32 filesystem

ADOPTABLE STORAGE: it's related to the ext4 filesystem, but I'm forced to use adoptable storage that I haven't understood very well how it's different from mounting manually, and if all apps can be installed into microSD or only the apps where it's explicitly mount such this command
mount -t sdcardfs -o nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,mask=7,gid=9997 /mnt/expand/[UUID]/media/0/WhatsApp /mnt/runtime/write/emulated/0/Whatsapp



So, from what I have understood, I have executed the following commands referred to link explanation:
mkdir /data/media/0/sdext2
mount -t ext4 -o rw /dev/block/mmcblk0p2 /data/media/0/sdext2
mkdir /data/media/0/sdext2/prova
restorecon -rv /data/media/
mount -t sdcardfs -o nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,mask=7,gid=9997 /data/media/0/sdext2/prova /mnt/runtime/write/emulated/0/prova

And I have made a folder called "prova" to verify that from /storage/emulated/0/prova I can see the only file inside /data/media/0/sdext2/prova. But nothing is viewed while if from X-plore I navigate into mnt/runtime/write/emulated/0/prova the file is shown.
Questions:

What are the commands to reach my goal? (I'm not an expert in Linux and Android)

When I use WhatsApp, the only important thing is that mnt/runtime/write/emulated/0/Whatsapp can read all files (and so no matter if from /storage/emulated/0/Whatsapp files aren't viewed?) Nothing can be made to read /storage/emulated/0/Whatsapp with files into MicroSD from X-plore as it's worked with local storage?

I don't remember how I created the second partition, but now the second partition is used by Link2SD and own and the group is system:system, and permission is drwxrwx--x. Is this ok?
Link2SD automatically mounts partitions into /data/sdext2, but if this is a problem, I can remove the mount inside /system/bin/debuggerd script

Can the new commands be added to /system/bin/debuggerd script? I'm not sure, but seems that the Android 10 firmware of my Galaxy S9 doesn't support init.d.



mkdir /mnt/my_sdcard && mount /dev/block/<SDCARD_PARTITION_BLOCK> /mnt/my_sdcard && mkdir -p /mnt/my_sdcard/WhatsApp && bindfs -o nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,context=u:object_r:sdcardfs:s0 -u 0 -g 9997 -p a-rwx,ug+rw,ugo+X --create-with-perms=a-rwx,ug+rw,ugo+X --xattr-none --chown-ignore --chgrp-ignore --chmod-ignore /mnt/my_sdcard/WhatsApp /mnt/runtime/write/emulated/0/WhatsApp. All this has been explained in the link you've provided.

I think it depends on what you mean with local WhatsApp directory - take note that expected file system is sdcardfs, and the path of WhatsApp Media has changed with scoped storage

@IrfanLatif thank for have answered me, bindfs it's not present inside /system/bin/sh. Inside terminal android can I execute "./configure && make && sudo make install" or not? Latest source code is compatible with abi of Linux kernel related to my firmware?

@alecxs for local WhatsApp directory I mean /storage/emulated/0/Whatsapp

@IrfanLatif how should I compile the last source code of bindfs? It's compatible last source cose with android 10 abi ? Should I compile also libfuse? Other questions: 1. what commands should I add to init.d service? 2. Can I continue to use partition with link2sd or not?

@n3o download link of bindfs pre-built binary is also available in the link you've provided.

@IrfanLatif so isn't necessary compile update source?if init.d isn'available, what is the best alternative to follow? 2. Can I continue to use partition with link2sd or not?

I have tried your commands with a directory named "prova" that contain one file inside microsd, but both from x.plore that from total commander if I  go to /storage/emulated/0/prova the directory is empty. the mount made from link2sd can be the cause? Should I disable the automatic mount from debuggerd? Should I run chmod 755 for bindfs after copied it in system/bin?

I have made new trial, I have modified debuggerd file to empty(so the second partition is no more mounted for LinktoSD), I have remade the step that You have listed but I can test that all works ok? If I try from x-plore the file inside second partition aren't showed, it's a limit of x-plore or command doesn't work? Moreover, after copied the bindfs file, after reboot I should copy newly, it's disappeared. Can You help me?
